# Median Calculation on Grouped Interval Data

Tags: probability, statistics, median

I was studying for my Probability & Statistics exam. I've encountered with an example which is about finding the median of a given grouped data. Here is the table of the data;

[image: Grouped Data Table]

So from the table, we are given that there are **51 children**. So when we want to find median, we know that it will be in **26th** position when we apply the formula as **(n+1)/2** since 51 is an odd number. When we look the frequencies in the table, we can see that **26th** children will be between **160 < h < 170** range. Here is the solution for finding the median which is given to me in the example;

[image: Solution]

What I didn't understand here is that how they calculated it in that way ? I understood the steps how they determined it should be between **160 < h < 170** range but I could not understand the following calculation **160 + (4/21)*10 = 162** . Can you please explain me, how this calculation works ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The $4$ comes from the fact that after you've disposed of the first $6,$ and then $16$ values, there are still $4$ left. So you start at the left-hand end of the interval, and estimate by computing $4/21$ of the way to the next interval boundary.

Comment: Actually, I would like to see a formula to use in another questions

Comment: Maybe something like this: $$\text{Est}=\text{LH Endpoint}+\frac{(\text{Num Past LH Endpoint})\cdot(\text{Bin Width})}{\text{Num In Bin}}.$$